# Error while creating new Database Connection

Tags: ireport

I am trying to add a new Database JDBC connection in iReport 5.6.0. Im using Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4213.0 . I have added mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar in the classpath of ireport tool.

[image: Here] is the screenshot of the connecting details.

When I test the connection it gives me the error msg Message:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
Level:
SEVERE
Stack Trace:
Communications link failure Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2103)
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:718)
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:302)
com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:282)
com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.connection.JDBCConnection.getConnection(JDBCConnection.java:140)
com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.connection.JDBCConnection.test(JDBCConnection.java:449)
com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.connection.gui.ConnectionDialog.jButtonTestActionPerformed(ConnectionDialog.java:335)
com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.connection.gui.ConnectionDialog.access$300(ConnectionDialog.java:43)
com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.connection.gui.ConnectionDialog$4.actionPerformed(ConnectionDialog.java:290)
```

Comment: in the screenshot it seems that you're using MySql and not sql server as you mentioned... is that correct?

Comment: yeah, you are right. It was such a silly mistake. Thanks!

Comment: did this solve the problem?

Comment: yes, the problem is solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the screenshot it seems that **you're using MySql** and **not sql server** as you mentioned.

Just choose the proper combination of Jar, Wizard setting and Database Vendor.